# recv() function is not receiving

Tags: c, linux, sockets, recv

SA,

I am trying to create socket and receive data and log from an Access Point, the code was working correctly when I run it from the shell. However, when I tried to connect to the AP from the code using execvp running the command

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "access point name"
```

the recv function is not working anymore neither from the code or the shell, it seems that some settings has changed when I run this command but I am not sure what exactly has changed

That's how I create the socket

```
memset(&proc_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_nl));
proc_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
proc_addr.nl_pid = getpid();            
proc_addr.nl_groups = CN_IDX_IWLAGN;

if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&proc_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_nl)) == -1)
    exit_program_err(-1, "bind");

{
    int on = proc_addr.nl_groups;
    ret = setsockopt(sock_fd, 270, NETLINK_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &on, sizeof(on));
    if (ret)
        exit_program_err(-1, "setsockopt");
}

while (1)
{
    /* Receive from socket with infinite timeout */
    printf("trying to receive");
    ret = recv(sock_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    printf("received");
}
```

So only trying to receive is printed and then nothing although I can ping data from the AP

The execvp code:

```
string cmd1_connect = "sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid ciscosb_3"; 
string cmd_check = "sudo dhclient wlan0";
 string cmd2_connect = "sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid Cisco13-guest"; 
while(true) { 
if(stream1) { 
shell->runcmd(&m, &cmd1_connect); 
shell->runcmd(&m, &cmd_check); 
} else { 
shell->runcmd(&m, &cmd2_connect); 
shell->runcmd(&m, &cmd_check); }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that calls `execvp`? Also, you really want `\n` at the end of those two `printf`s, otherwise buffering can fool you about when that code is actually running.

Comment: `string cmd1_connect = "sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid ciscosb_3";
string cmd_check = "sudo dhclient wlan0";
string cmd2_connect = "sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid Cisco13-guest";
while(true) {
   if(stream1) {
 shell->runcmd(&m, &cmd1_connect);
        shell->runcmd(&m, &cmd_check);
   } else {
        shell->runcmd(&m, &cmd2_connect);
 shell->runcmd(&m, &cmd_check);
}`

Comment: Actually in this code I try to switch between two APs also I tried the \n in the print messages but only the first was printed

Comment: Are you calling `fork` before `execvp`?  IIRC, `execvp` replaces the currently running process.  Also, you will not see `printf` output without the trailing newlines until a buffer fills.  Either put in the newlines or call `setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 ); setvbuf( stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );`

Comment: yes I am actually calling fork before execvp and I added the new lines but it seems there is another problem with recv

Comment: What is the returned value of `recv`? How do you declare `buf`? And how do you _actually_ create `sock_fd` (i.e. the call to `socket`)?

Comment: `sock_fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_CONNECTOR);
if (sock_fd == -1)
    exit_program_err(-1, "socket");
char buf[4096];
int ret;`